# Table View data not populating

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5

My table view data (ie populated in an array) is not loading when I set up cell background image. But it is working fine with out the cell background image.

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your background image using

```
UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]];

[cell setBackgroundView:imgView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted code here of that Table View Method if possible than post it.

I think if the Cell image color Match with the Text color of the content you are displaying than it'll be there but not visible.

Second thing if you have added Cell image by this Code :

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:cellImage];
```

& if you have written the CellImage code Below the Text Content then also it'll be not displayed.

Hope this will help.